I cant execute code because of SSH Authentication error
I am working on a code that: Executes client command during TCP Server.
Server code:
import socket
import paramiko
import threading

# SSH sunucu bilgileri
SSH_HOST = ("localhost")
SSH_PORT = 22
SSH_USERNAME = "skonuvs"
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = "/home/skonuvs/rsakeys"
SSH_PASS = "lelele"


# TCP sunucu bilgileri
TCP_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
TCP_PORT = 53953

def ssh_connect(command):
    # SSH istemcisi oluştur
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        # Özel anahtarı yükle
        ssh_private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)

        # Sunucuya bağlan
        client.connect(SSH_HOST, port=SSH_PORT, username=SSH_USERNAME,password=SSH_PASS, pkey=ssh_private_key)
        print(f"Connected to {SSH_HOST}")

        # Komut çalıştırma
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
        output = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
        client.send(output.encode())
        return output

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to connect to {SSH_HOST}: {e}")
        return str(e).encode()  # Hata durumunda dönecek veriyi encode edin

    finally:
        # Bağlantıyı kapat
        client.close()

def handle_client(client_socket):
    print("Client handler started")
    while True:
        try:
            # İstemciden veri al
            command = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            if not command:
                break

            print(f"Executing command: {command}")
            output = ssh_connect(command)
            client_socket.send(output)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error handling client: {e}")
            break

    # Bağlantıları kapat
    client_socket.close()

def start_server():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((TCP_HOST, TCP_PORT))
    server.listen(5)
    print(f"Listening on {TCP_HOST}:{TCP_PORT}")

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"Accepted connection from {addr}")
        client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
        client_handler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()


Client code
import socket

# TCP sunucu bilgileri
TCP_HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # Sunucu adresini buraya yazın
TCP_PORT = 53953

def start_client():
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((TCP_HOST, TCP_PORT))
    print(f"Connected to TCP server at {TCP_HOST}:{TCP_PORT}")

    while True:
        command = input("Enter command to execute on SSH server: ")
        if command.lower() == "exit":
            break

        # Komutu sunucuya gönder
        client.send(command.encode())

        # Sunucudan sonucu al
        response = client.recv(1024).decode()
        print(f"Response:\n{response}")

    # Bağlantıyı kapat
    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_client()


And when I run at the terminal, I get this error:
Listening on 0.0.0.0:53953
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 42594)
Client handler started
Executing command: ls -la
Failed to connect to localhost: Authentication failed.

Note: Its not about permissions. I have given all permissions to servers, clients, keys.
I tried changing ip and addresses but it didn't worked either.

A working code for: 1) default public key auth import paramiko; client = paramiko.SSHClient(); client.load_system_host_keys();  client.connect('127.0.0.1', port=22); client.exec_command('ls -l') 2) password auth import paramiko; client = paramiko.SSHClient(); client.load_system_host_keys();  client.connect('127.0.0.1', port=22, username='user', password='password'); client.exec_command('ls -l')

@Muhammed Do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] with debugging details. Did you check the log? See this.

Why does your server code contains code for connecting to a server and loading a private key? Both is not needed on the server side so it is not clear why it is contained in your code.
